# Android Studio SDK installer hangs indefinitely at Unzipping 'platform-tools/systrace/NOTICE'

Tags: android, android-studio

adb is not available from command prompt (with correct path set).  I think something failed in the original installation of the platform-tools.  Studio is telling me to update but this happens every time:

[image: where the installer gets stuck]

it looks like adb.exe is missing from my machine

this is the android studio event log:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i had the same problem the adb.exe was deleted i downloaded the adb shell from http://adbshell.com/downloads

and extracted the adb.exe in the android sdk location "AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools"

Answer (score 5):

delete platform-tools from this location
C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Then restart Android Studio.
After gradle build finish it will ask for installation of missing tools. just click there. It should work fine.

Comment: I have deleted the platform-tools (To locate it, please check Android SDK Location  under SDK Manager). Then I uninstalled and installed the Android SDK Platform-Tools

Comment: Mac: `/Users/<USERNAME>/Library/Android/sdk`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. My adb.exe has been deleted by my antivirus software. adb.exe couldn't be started and therefore couldn't be stopped. All i had to do to fix this problem was to restore the file with my antivirus software.I hope this helps future Viewers.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to repair the installation so I just completely uninstalled Android Studio and deleted `~/AppData/Local/Android` folder.  Then I reinstalled Android Studio and the necessary SDKs.

I believe my original installation failed and was missing parts (like adb) and this was causing the update to fail as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I overwrite android studio directory (in Program Files) with new version and try to update the SDK.

I deleted the old version of android studio, replaced the entire directory with new version and unzip works.