# adb devices list my phones but android studio does not show this

Tags: android-studio

i just install windows 10 ver 1809, on command line adb devices shows my 2 phones

```
adb devices
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached
***62aa4        device
***9389a        device
```

but from android studio there are not devices, i have an emulator that appear on list but android studio  can't connnect to emulator either.

android studio 3.2.1
Android sdk tools 26.1.1

the usb cable works good in other machines

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution here  in other post.

```
go to SDK Platform Tools;
download SDK Platform-Tools for Windows; 
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html
extract zip file and copy to \AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools.
```

[android studio platform-tools missing adb.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44038199/android-studio-platform-tools-missing-adb-exe)