# I have remove adb file from platform tools

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I have delete adb from platform tools for android studio

I want to restore it again, but i couldn't find it in trash

How can I do that?

Comment: check this post pls https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44038199/android-studio-platform-tools-missing-adb-exe/47671448

Answer (score 0):

this solution works for me [android studio platform-tools missing adb.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44038199/android-studio-platform-tools-missing-adb-exe/47671448)

I am writing the solution which worked for me:

- go to SDK Platform Tools
- download SDK Platform-Tools for Windows
- extract zip file and copy to
  \AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools.